# what SQL Query for get summation like below result Output

Tags: sql, sql-server

what SQL Query for get summation like below result Output

[image: Sample ScreenShot]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT item, SUM(SalePrice) as SalePrice, date 
FROM PurchasedProducts 
WHERE date = '2019-04-28' 
GROUP BY item, date
```

Try this. It should work.

Comment: Would appreciate if you upvote/ accept the answer :)